# MS SQL - Get matching fields for every ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table X and tables Y and Z
Table X contains IDs of members and table Y,Z contain relevant data for that ID

What I am trying to do is to grab the data from table Y,Z for every ID in Table X

**Sample Data**
Table X

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  |    Name    |
+-----+------------+
| 121 | Joe Schmoe |
| 123 | Jill Blink |
| 125 | John Doe   |
| 129 | Johny Doe  |
| 191 | King Kong  |
+-----+------------+
```

Table Y

```
+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID  |     Address      |  City  | State |  Zip  |
+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
| 121 | 123 Main         | Dallas | TX    | 75240 |
| 123 | 3403 South 21st  | Austin | TX    | 75241 |
| 125 | 1012 Worthington | Miami  | FL    | 34542 |
+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Table Z

```
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Age |
+-----+-----+
| 125 |  65 |
| 129 |  32 |
| 121 |  36 |
+-----+-----+
```

**RESULTS**

```
+-----+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID  | Age |     Address      |  City  | State |  Zip  |
+-----+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
| 121 |     | 123 Main         | Dallas | TX    | 75240 |
| 123 |     | 3403 South 21st  | Austin | TX    | 75241 |
| 125 |  65 | 1012 Worthington | Miami  | FL    | 34542 |
| 129 |  32 |                  |        |       |       |
+-----+-----+------------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Help us help you - can you share the sample data used to create this result?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
Select X.*,Y.*,Z.* from 
X inner join Y on X.Id = Y.XId
inner join Z on X.Id = Z.XId
```

Comment: I am trying to. SOF wont allow me to add tables into my questions

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` each table. Use `WHERE` to make sure at least one of Y and Z match.

```
select x.id, z.age, y.Address, y.City, y.State, y.Zip  
from x
left join y on x.id = y.id
left join z on x.id = z.id
where y.id is not null or z.id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `full join` and dispense with the `x` table:

```
select coalesce(y.xid, z.xid) as id,
       y.address, y.city, y.state, y.zip,
       z.age
from y full join
     z
     on y.xid = z.xid
```